# Lightning Community: v.body on Custom Template is initialized even inside an aura:if

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, rendering, aura-if, page-template

I have a **Lightning Community** and I'm using a custom HTML template to render my pages, inside this HTML template I have a **v.body** where my custom components are being displayed (the ones selected from the community builder).

So the weird thing I found out is that even when I code this:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!false}">
    {!v.body}
</aura:if>
```

The init handler of my custom components that go inside the "aura:if" is executed, although the components are not displayed on the DOM.

This is a big problem for me since I'm loading an external library on my HTML Template and rendering the {!v.body} **afterScriptsLoaded**, but my components keep crashing because my custom components use those libraries and the init handler keeps executing even when the isTrue statement is **false**. And I don't want to add my scripts on every single component inside my pages.

This seems to be a lightning bug, but I would like to be sure about this.

Answer (score 3):

So, the specifications for `aura:if` explicitly state it needs an expression, however the attribute `isTrue` itself does say its a boolean.

Given that, I would expect your syntax to work however it looks like it may be treating it is a truthy String.

The easiest fix is to pass in an attribute like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{! v.myBool }">
 ...
</aura:if>
```

Comment: the component is not being rendered, that means that my code is working. However, the "init" event is still being executed, that I think is the bug, Lightning is initialising the component even if the condition is false, but I guess this is because is a Page Component inside a Lightning community.

Answer (score 2):

You could load your scripts into just one component and call it using promises. Then you never need to worry about afterscriptsloaded or bad references.

You'd have a component - say called "ScriptLoader".

ScriptLoader would have these top level attributes:

```
<aura:attribute name="yourscriptsource" type="String" default="{!$Resource.yourscriptname}"/>
<div>
  <div class="scriptdiv" id="{!GlobalId + '_scriptdiv'}"/>
</div>
<aura:attribute name="scriptsLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

Plus a public method like this:

```
getYourScript: function(component) {
  return new Promise($A.getCallback(function(resolve, reject) {

    if (component.get("v.scriptsLoaded") == true) {
      resolve(window.yourscript);
    } 
    else {

      // Create script element and set attributes
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.async = true;
      //resource reference to your script 
      script.src = component.get("v.yourscriptsource");

      var el = document.getElementsByClassName('scriptdiv')[0];
      el.parentNode.insertBefore(script, el);

      // Resolve the promise once the script is loaded
      script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        component.set("v.scriptsLoaded", true);
        resolve(window.yourscript);
      });

      // Catch any errors while loading the script
      script.addEventListener('error', () => {
        reject('yourscript failed to load');
      });
    }

  }))
},
```

Assuming you have defined this method as an `aura:method` on the component, you can then call it like this:

```
var scriptLoader = component.find('scriptLoader');
scriptLoader.getYourScript()
  .then(
    yourscript => {
      yourscript.something()
    }
  )
  .then(
    (someresult) => {
      //do something else
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess that would work if the caller component is the parent component, but this is not my case, and I would prefer not adding this 'ScriptLoader' component everywhere or having to add any logic inside every component that needs the script.

Comment: Yes, if you were to use the component only for loading scripts, then you mayaswell just use the built in loader. However, I actually use this component for most DML and SOQL calls (when I'm not using a recorddata component), so it becomes quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to replace `aura:if` with `aura:renderIf` it is little bit different and does not render any content until variable changes. Salesforce states it is slower, but I had multiple issues with `aura:if` that were simply resolved by using `aura:renderIf`

Comment: `aura:renderIf` is deprecated, so you are taking a pretty big risk that this function will entirely disappear.

Comment: I know it is, but `aura:if` is broken in some cases.

Comment: @Paul which cases? I've been using it quite reliably

Comment: If you could show us some cases of it not working (maybe in a new linked ticket)  we might be able to debug for you... I'm pretty sure `aura:if` is solid